# how to set rating bar value using simple adapter on android studio

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, ratingbar, simpleadapter

This is my activity java class and use Volly libry to get data from server as a json array. so I want to get rating value from server and set it to the rating bar.

ListActivity.java

```
public void LoadList() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="http://beezzserver.com/slthadi/projectPHI/place/index.php?Lid="+lid+"&gid="+gid+"&cid="+cid+"";

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    setPlace(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    queue.add(request);
}

public void  setPlace(JSONArray response){

    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try {
        for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++){

            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("id", object.getString("id"));
            map.put("name", object.getString("name"));
            map.put("rating", object.getString("reating"));  //need to set this value to rating bar

            map.put("img", Integer.toString(array[i]));
            list.add(map);

        }

        int layout = R.layout.item_placelist;
        int[] views = {R.id.pid,R.id.tvName,R.id.rtbPlace};        //this not work
        String[] colums = {"id","name","rating"};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,list,layout,colums,views);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my list item layout

item_placelist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp">

   .............. other codings.....................

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rtbPlace"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/textDark"
                android:progressTint="@color/colorGreenSpc"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="3.5"
                android:layout_gravity="end"/>

            ......................other code...............

</LinearLayout>
```

How I set the value of rating bar using simple adapter? I trying to resole this using based some question in this. but I cant find some real solutio for thif.

Comment: According to document, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter, SimpleAdapter does not fill up RatingBar. You have to extend the adapter and fill it up by yourselves.

Comment: opz.Thankyou. I'll consider about it.